# HTML Javascript URL Parameters not lined up in a row by klicking second time on a next button

Tags: javascript, php, html

for test and understanding for my project:
I want a php-page  which shows me the current date of the week and a link which I can go one week forward.
In the URL I send the date to the next side, if I have a datetime in URL (so the first "next" click) it should show me the next week and also a next-Button to go to the next week (2. week) and so on...
(Background is I want have a weekcalendar (Monday to Friday) with buttons previous week and next week.)

Currently I have the problem, that the browser adds in the url my sended date as a added row.
But I want only one date and not the previous sended dates before.

Currently: HTTPPAGENAME/?next=1653915514?next=1653915516

If i clicked to times on next.
[Wrong Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bx80.png)

But I only want only: HTTPPAGENAME/?next=1653915516

when I click for two times.

The rest of the code is not finished, currently it is only the url-row-think.

Whats the clue on that?

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
    $weekdate = time(); 
    
    $tmpstringurl = strtotime("+ 1 week", $weekdate);

if(isset($_GET['next'])) {
//Test not finished
    $tmpstringurl = strtotime("+ 1 week", $weekdate);

} else {
//Test not finished
    $tmpstringurl = strtotime("+ 1 week", $weekdate);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

<p><label>Date: <?php echo date("d.m.Y", $weekdate) ?></label></p><br/>

<a href="" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?next='+<?php echo $tmpstringurl ?>;return false;">One week more</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The onclick code grabs the complete url and adds the <?php echo $tmpstringurl ?> along with it causes ?next=123/next=123. So modify the onclick value to getting only host domain or use href="" link instead.

Comment: Thank you.
So yeah! I see that location.href=this.href gets everytime the current url, and the next url is with ?next... and so on...

I had no idea what I could change in this. I think there should be a easy version, but currently I don't know.

So I used this:
`<a href ="javascript:openPage()";return false;>Next  </a>`  `<script>`  `openPage = function() {`  `location.href = "?next="+<?php echo $tmpstringurl ?>;`  `}`  `</script>`

Comment: And okay, the easy version is this:

`<a href="?next=<?php echo $tmpstringurl; ?>">One week more</a>`
Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have re coded your snippet below.

```
<?php
    # By Ajmal PraveeN (AP)
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
    $weekdate = time(); 
    
    $tmpstringurl = strtotime("+ 1 week", $weekdate);

if(isset($_GET['next'])) {
//Test not finished
    $tmpstringurl = strtotime("+ 1 week", $weekdate);

} else {
//Test not finished
    $tmpstringurl = strtotime("+ 1 week", $weekdate);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

<p><label>Date: <?php echo date("d.m.Y", $weekdate); ?></label></p><br/>

<a href="/?next=<?php echo $tmpstringurl; ?>" title="One week more">One week more</a>

</body>
</html>
```

If this is useful upvote.